# Find Folders including AD username

Tags: powershell

I just want to simply get all the folders for all the users in an OU

I have tried `Get-ChildItem -path "\\test\foldertest\" -include $users`

eg: `$user = john.doe, test.2`

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Departed Users,OU=DISABLED,OU=To Decommission,DC=internal,DC=local" -Filter *

Get-childitem -path C:\ -include $users -recurse
```

I have also tried to export it to csv and import it and then run a `for-each loop`

```
eg: import-csv C:\test.csv | foreach {get-childitem -path $path}
```

I should get a list of all items/folders with all the users name in the `$user` varible

Comment: unless i am reading your code snippets wrong, you are trying to use an ENTIRE object in your comparison. `$Users` looks like it will be an array of _ad user objects_ ... not a simple string. try replacing your `$Users` reference with `$Users.SamAccountName` or whatever property contains the name that you use for your user directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $userlist = "johndoe", "testuser"

 foreach ($user in $userlist)

 {

 $searchfilter = (get-aduser $user | select Samaccountname).Samaccountname
 dir $searchfilter 

 }
```

This should work I believe

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are looking for is something like this:

```
$rootFolder = '\\test\foldertest'

# get a list of all user SamAccountNames in the given OU and wrap these names with asterikses to use as wildcards for '-Include'
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Departed Users,OU=DISABLED,OU=To Decommission,DC=internal,DC=local" -Filter * | 
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | ForEach-Object { "*$_*" }

# next search the rootfolder recursively for any directory where a the name includes a AD SamAccountNames
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Directory -Include $users -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

If you suspect there may me hidden folders aswell, append the `-Force` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.